# Disabling auth/user-not-found functionality

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a React application with email & password sign in method available (implemented with firebase). In the log in form, if you enter incorrect email, you will get [auth/user-not-found](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#error-codes) error as expected.

What are my options to disable this kind of behaviour? To me it seems to be a security risk where malicious user could query email addresses and see if the user exists on my platform or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot disable what firebase would respond with, but you should handle the error in your client to show a less specific response.

```
try {
...
} catch (err) {
  if (err.code === 'auth/user-not-found') {
     alert("Invalid email address and/or password")
  } else {
    console.log("Other error handling method")
  }
}
```

Comment: Removing the error from UI doesn't remove the security concern. You could still see the actual error on the browsers developer tools network tab and could easily replicate the call. However, as someone pointed me out, user registration form would have exactly the same problem ("email address already exists") so this might be a tradeoff that allows for a slightly better user experience.

I'll mark this as an answer as there is not much a developer could do, or if even should. Hiding this information from UI is maybe the best thing you could do about this "concern".

Answer (score 0):

I was actually looking up for a solution to this problem and stumbled upon this question before actually finding an answer.

**Answer**
Firebase Auth seems to have added a feature called "Email enumeration protection" that is disabled by default for older projects, but enabled on newer ones (September 15, 2023 cutline). Docs: https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/admin/email-enumeration-protection
You can find this setting inside **[your project] -> Authentication -> User actions**

This should solve the problem if anyone stumbles upon it for some older Firebase Auth proejct.